# How to fix aggregate query and update query in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to MongoDB. I started a Python project, that for which I should use pymongo library.
My JSON contains records about computers.
Every computer has brand and price.
I wrote a query that calculates the average price for computer for each company. This calculation should be calculate every day. 
In other words, I want to update the average records if there are records (my script ran more than one time), if there are no records, I want to add them. Any ideas how to implement it?
I read that Mongo has update function as SQL has, but no matter how many times I tried to use it, it fail. I guess my problem is something in the syntax 
or maybe it something else, but I don't get it. I would appreciate any help.

```
avg_price = self._collection_name.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": "$Brand", "Avg price": {"$avg": "$Price"}}}])

update = self._collection_name.update({'_id': 'Brand'},  {'$set': {"Avg price": "$Price"}}, upsert=True)
```

Comment: What does "it failing" mean. Is there an error message?

Comment: No. I know I have a logical error in the first query (avg_price), since my key is the brand. so If I want to update all the brands, I guess I need to write the update query for each brand. What I am looking for is a solution for the first query, so when I get to the update query, I will update all records that contains avg calculation at once.